# What is the best practice for committing changes using a LINQ2SQL datacontext in a Silverlight application using RIA?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datacontext, ria, submitchanges

I've got a Silverlight app using RIA services and LINQ2SQL and have objects in my Silverlight app.

I query all the records in a table (via a LINQ query, using a datacontext) in the Silverlight app and create a user control for each object (record) and put that object into the control because I need the information later.   Then later, the user makes changes to that object (stored in the control) and I want to save it back to the database.

My problem is that when I go to save the object I have no datacontext to execute SubmitChanges against.  I can't attach it to a new context because it says it's already attached.

What the best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new DataContext, use it to retrieve the record in question, make your changes to the record, and execute SubmitChanges().

Comment: So there's no way to use the record I've stored in the control?  I need to get it again, copy the contents of the stored record into it and SubmitChanges() on that?  Seems kinda redundant since I already have a record.  The record I have is quite simple, so it would be easy in this case, but if I had a complex record (object) it would soon get pretty ugly to copy over.

Comment: If you have a way to databind the record, you might get away with not having to copy all the values.  Have a look here: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Introducing-Two-Way-Data-Binding-using-Silverlight-20-WCF-and-LINQ-to-SQL/